# mutate multiple column value under ifelse condition in R

Tags: r

I have a df with two columns (ID and group),and another dt with two columns(group, pos), I would like to mutate multiple columns(group column of df) with value exist in pos range(dt) in R. I only can handle column one by one.Thanks!

```
df <- data.frame(ID = LETTERS[1:10],
                 group =  c("001", "051", "211.5", "047", "154", "73.9", "015", "008", "628", "7.6")

dt <- data.frame(group = c("001", "051", "211.5", "047", "154", "73.9", "015", "008", "628", "7.6"),
                 pos = c("001-009.99", "050-079.99", "110-118.99", "110-118.99", "188-189.99", "195-199.99", "214-215.99", "214-215.99", "249-250.99", "001-007"))

# separate pos info to new columns
dt <-  dt %>% separate(pos, into = c('pos1', 'pos2'), sep = "\\-") %>% mutate(group = as.numeric(group))

group_by(dt, group) %>% mutate("001" = ifelse( 1 < group & group < 9.99, "In range", "Not In"))
```

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
# Groups:   group [6]
  group pos1  pos2   `001` 
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr> 
1   1   001   009.99 Not In
2  51   050   079.99 Not In
3 212.  110   118.99 Not In
4  47   110   118.99 Not In
5 154   188   189.99 Not In
6  73.9 195   199.99 Not In
```

expected output want like

```
# A tibble: 6 × 13
# Groups:   group [6]
  ID  group pos1  pos2   `001`  `051`    `211.5` `047`  `154`  `73.9` `015`  `008`  `628`  `7.6` 
      <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1  A    1   001   009.99 Not In Not In   Not In  Not In Not In Not In Not In Not In Not In Not In
2  B   51   050   079.99 Not In In range Not In  Not In Not In Not In Not In Not In Not In Not In
3  C  212.5  110   118.99 Not In Not In   Not In  Not In Not In Not In Not In Not In Not In Not In
4  D   47   110   118.99 Not In Not In   Not In  Not In Not In Not In Not In Not In Not In Not In
5  E  154   188   189.99 Not In Not In   Not In  Not In Not In Not In Not In Not In Not In Not In
6  F   73.9 195   199.99 Not In In range Not In  Not In Not In Not In Not In Not In Not In Not In
```

Comment: @Darren Tsai, Hi, I update  expected output. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `read.csv` second, use `data.table::between` and make a `diag` out of it. I don't understand the logic of your ranges, though.

```
res <- data.frame(group=as.numeric(dt$group), pos=unname(read.csv(header=F, text=dt$pos, sep='-')))
res <- cbind(res, `colnames<-`(diag(do.call(data.table::between, unname(res))), dt$group))
res
#    group pos.1  pos.2   001   051 211.5   047   154  73.9   015   008   628   7.6
# 1    1.0     1   9.99  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 2   51.0    50  79.99 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 3  211.5   110 118.99 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 4   47.0   110 118.99 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 5  154.0   188 189.99 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 6   73.9   195 199.99 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 7   15.0   214 215.99 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 8    8.0   214 215.99 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 9  628.0   249 250.99 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 10   7.6     1   7.00 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

If needed you can easily convert the booleans:

```
res[-(1:3)] <- lapply(+res[-(1:3)], factor, levels=0:1, labels=c('Not in', 'In range'))
res
#    group pos.1  pos.2      001      051  211.5    047    154   73.9    015    008    628    7.6
# 1    1.0     1   9.99 In range   Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in
# 2   51.0    50  79.99   Not in In range Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in
# 3  211.5   110 118.99   Not in   Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in
# 4   47.0   110 118.99   Not in   Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in
# 5  154.0   188 189.99   Not in   Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in
# 6   73.9   195 199.99   Not in   Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in
# 7   15.0   214 215.99   Not in   Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in
# 8    8.0   214 215.99   Not in   Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in
# 9  628.0   249 250.99   Not in   Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in
# 10   7.6     1   7.00   Not in   Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in Not in
```

---

*Data*

```
dt <- structure(list(group = c("001", "051", "211.5", "047", "154", 
"73.9", "015", "008", "628", "7.6"), pos = c("001-009.99", "050-079.99", 
"110-118.99", "110-118.99", "188-189.99", "195-199.99", "214-215.99", 
"214-215.99", "249-250.99", "001-007")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```